# "stacking" arrays in a new dimension?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider, for reference:

```
>>> x, y = np.ones((2, 2, 2)), np.zeros((2, 2, 2))
>>> np.concatenate((x, y, x, y), axis=2)
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

We have stacked the arrays along the innermost dimension, merging it - the resulting shape is `(2, 2, 8)`. But suppose I wanted those innermost elements to lie side-by-side instead (this would only work because every dimension of the source arrays is the same, including the one I want to 'stack' in), producing a result with shape `(2, 2, 4, 2)` as follows?

```
array([[[[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
```

The best approach I have is to reshape each source array first, to add a 1-length dimension right before the last:

```
def pad(npa):
    return npa.reshape(npa.shape[:-1] + (1, npa.shape[-1]))

np.concatenate((pad(x), pad(y), pad(x), pad(y)), axis=2) # does what I want
# np.hstack might be better? I always want the second-last dimension, now
```

But I feel like I am reinventing a wheel. Have I overlooked something that will do this more directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
>>> xx = x[..., None, :]
>>> yy = y[..., None, :]
>>> np.concatenate((xx, yy, xx, yy), axis=2).shape
(2, 2, 4, 2)
>>> np.concatenate((xx, yy, xx, yy), axis=2)
array([[[[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.],
         [ 1.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
>>>
```

What this example does is change the shape (no data is copied) of the arrays. Slicing with `None` or equivalently `np.newaxis` adds an axis:

```
>>> xx.shape
(2, 2, 1, 2)
>>> xx
array([[[[ 1.,  1.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.]]],


       [[[ 1.,  1.]],

        [[ 1.,  1.]]]])
>>>
```

Comment: There is no broadcasting here, you're just adding a dimension using newaxis.

Comment: I'd recommend removing any reference to adding axes using `None`. It is bad practice. `np.newaxis` is the way to go. The maxime is *be explicit*: naming is everything, or at least a lot. Take a look at [this magic line](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L361)

Comment: @eickenberg it's in the docs too: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis Bi Rico you are right I was on autopilot, editing

Comment: @BiRico it's clearly a simpler way to add the dimension than what I clumsily put together, though. :)