# Efficiently combining Numpy arrays, growing into new dimension

Tags: python, list, numpy, stack, concatenation

How can I efficiently create a numpy tensor that collects many matrices and stacks them, always adding new matrices. This is useful for managing batches of images, for example, where each image is a 3D matrix. Stacking **N**, 3D images (one dimension for each of the RGB planes) together creates a 4D matrix.

Here is [the base form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898471/concatenate-two-numpy-arrays-in-the-4th-dimension) of simply appending to matrices into a new dimension, creating a final matrix of higher dimension than the original two. And here is [some information on the `np.newaxis` functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/the-use-of-numpy-newaxis).

Comment: Why are people voting down and not giving any advice?

Comment: They probably have something against self-answered questions. Self-answered questions are [explicitly okay and officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), guys.

Comment: @user2357112 - Thanks. I actually post this stuff because I couldn't find a specific answer to my question and so want to save other people the time it cost me. Also, I hope someone maybe thinks of a better way! :)

Comment: You can also use `np.fromiter`', I've benchmarked it in an answer here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860970/why-use-numpy-over-list-based-on-speed/46868693#46868693.  It compares well to using numpy lists.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two good ways I know of, which use some ways from the links of the question as building blocks.

If you create an array e.g. with 3 dimensions and on the fly would like to keep appending these singular results to one another, thus creating a 4d tensor, then you require a small amount of initial setup for the first array before you can apply the answers posted in the question.

One approach is to store all the single matrices in a list (appending as you go) and then simply to combine them using `np.array`:

```
def list_version(input_data, N):

    outputs = []
    for i in range(N):
        one_matrix = function_creating_single_matrix(arg1, arg2)
        outputs.append(one_matrix)

    return np.array(outputs)
```

A second approach extends the very first matrix (e.g. that is 3d) to become 4d, using `np.newaxis`. Subsequent 3d matrices can then be `np.concatenate`d one-by-one. They must also be extended in the same dimension as the very first matrix - the final result *grows* in this dimension. Here is an example:

```
def concat_version(input_data, N):

    for i in range(N):
        if i == 0:
            results = function_creating_single_matrix(arg1, arg2)
            results = results[np.newaxis,...]    # add the new dimension
        else:
            output = function_creating_single_matrix(arg1, arg2)
            results = np.concatenate((results, output[np.newaxis,...]), axis=0)
            # the results are growing the the first dimension (=0)

    return results
```

I also compared the variants in terms of performance using Jupyter `%%timeit` cells. In order to make the pseudocode above work, I just created simple matrices filled with ones, to be appended to one another:

```
function_creating_single_matrix() = np.ones(shape=(10, 50, 50))
```

I can then also compare the results to ensure it is the same.

```
%%timeit -n 100
resized = list_version(N=100)
# 4.97 ms ± 25.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
resized = concat_version(N=100)
# 96.6 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So it seems that **the list method is ~20 times faster!** ...at least on these scales of matrix-magnitude

Here we see that the functions return identical results:

```
list_output = list_version(N=100)
concat_output = concat_version(N=100)
np.array_equal(list_output, concat_output)
# True
```

I also ran `cProfile` on the functions, and it seems the reason is that `np.concatenate` spends a lot of its time copying the matrices. I then traced this back to [the underlying C code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c73335920c300bf09a48226e0d590ba0e8eac654/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L346).

#### Links:

- Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143795/stacking-arrays-in-a-new-dimension) that stacks several arrays, but assuming they are already in existence, not being generated and appended on the fly.
- Here is [some more discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array) on the memory management and speed of the above mentioned methods.

Comment: Calling `concatenate` in a loop is terrible for performance because every call has to allocate an entire new array and copy the arguments into the new array. Gathering them into a list and building the final array in one call is the way to go.

Comment: @n1k31t4 thanks for sharing. unfortunately, the competitive culture in this site (or the brain damage due to programming in excess) is to destroy the efforts of others.